# magento reindex product_eav

Tags: php, magento, reindex

Im having trouble rindexing product_data, i get this error:
(p.s i've recently changed hosting and i re-index through Shell as the adminhtml timesout)

```
Product Flat Data index process unknown error:exception 'PDOException' with message
'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 
1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`britwear_magento`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-55fda_1226f51'>,
CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT_2_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` 
FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_e)' 
in /home2/britwear/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:

#0 /home2/britwear/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home2/britwear/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home2/britwear/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home2/britwear/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home2/britwear/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#5 /home2/britwear/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#6 /home2/britwear/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(327): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#7 /home2/britwear/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2548): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->raw_query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#8 /home2/britwear/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(806): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->addForeignKey('FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT...', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE')
#9 /home2/britwear/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(125):  Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->prepareFlatTable(2)
#10 /home2/britwear/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(115): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->rebuild('2')
#11 /home2/britwear/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(73): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->rebuild(NULL)
#12 /home2/britwear/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(303): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer->rebuild()
#13 /home2/britwear/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(166): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#14 /home2/britwear/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(194): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#15 /home2/britwear/public_html/magento/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#16 /home2/britwear/public_html/magento/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#17 {main}
```

i assume i have to remove a foreign key constraint in phpMyAdmin but im not sure where?

Comment: You better not remove that constraint, you get the error for a reason. Instead find what actually causes the error to fix your data and or code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drop table catalog_product_flat_ (Drop flat catalog)

php shell/indexer.php reindexall (Have magento index

Answer (score 1):

Try to select both tables and fix possible problems. You may remove ids from some tables, or you may add scecific ids so you can reindex now and delete next.
Can you explain what you did to get this error?

Comment: im sorry i dont understand what you mean, to get the error i ran a renindexing in SHELL using the following command: php indexer.php reindexall, Product Flat Data gave this error, everything else reindexed scussfully.

Comment: Ok.When you have database errors an reindexing failed is not as easy as that.